# How to transform 1 line with multiple in 2 lines with multiple columns on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to do a query to return the following result:

[image]

I tried with `UNPIVOT` but it doesen't work. I have the 12 months, but for example I put just 2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select t.Sector, tt.*
from table t cross apply
     ( values ('Jan', Jan_Estimated, Jan_Sold),
              ('Feb', Feb_Estimated, Feb_Sold),
               . . .
     ) tt (Month, Val_Estimated, Val_Sold);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT tab.sector, sub.* 
FROM tab
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Jan', Jan_estimated, Jan_sold),
                    ('Feb', Feb_estimated, Feb_sold)
  )sub(Month,Val_estimated, Val_sold)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT  sector, [Month] = Substring(col1,1,3), val_Estimated, val_Sold
FROM    ( 
    SELECT * FROM [tableName] 
) as t 
UNPIVOT ( val_Estimated for col1 IN (jan_estimated,feb_estimated)) AS unpvt 
UNPIVOT ( val_Sold for col2 in (jan_sold, feb_sold)) up2
WHERE SUBSTRING(col1,1,3) = SUBSTRING(col2,1,3)
```